# Moving to previous region in *nix Screen

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have been a fan of **Screen** for quite some time now, and I often like to have three separate "regions" (what is created with "Ctrl-a + S" or "Ctrl-a + |"). Now when I am in a region and I want to go back one, I have been performing "Ctrl-a + Tab" twice to simply move back a region. After extensive searching online and analyzing a cheat sheet [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/screen.htm), I have yet to find the opposite to the "Ctrl-a-Tab" command. Can someone throw me a bone?

Comment: This doesn't really belong here. Try over at super user or some such...

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14142/40697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no keybinding for this behavior available by default, but you can create one by adding the following line to your `.screenrc`:

```
bind Q focus up
```

where `Q` is a character of your choice; pressing `CTRL-A Q` will then move back one region.